# xfce - how to pin app to workspace during execution

Tags: xfce, window

Running Xubuntu 16.04. (*This is not related to "session restore on startup" as that works fine :)*

My browser (Chrome) is on workspace 1 and my Slack app is on workspace 2.

Whenever I click a link in the Slack app (quite often ;) my browser jumps from WS1 to WS2. I would like my browser to remain on WS1, whatever happens. Would that be possible in XFCE? TIA for any suggestions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to Settings Manager > Window Manager Tweaks > Focus tab. In the "When a window raises itself" section, select an option other than "Bring window on current workspace".

Comment: Followed by "punch whoever thought this was a good default in the face."

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been annoyed by this for many months :)